# What Algorithm Changes A JPEG (YCbCr) format to an RGB format?

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

Whenever I search for this on google I always only get the algorithm that converts an RGB image into a JPEG, but never the other way around. Or I get some library that does that for me. I want to know how it actually happens. What algorithm is used and where can I find the step-by-step for it?

Thanks :)

Comment: So are you asking about the [color space conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#JPEG_conversion) or the [compression and decompression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Decoding)?

Comment: kind of misleading, as RGB is color mode, on the other hand `.jpg` is extension. Rather the question description should be how to convert `YCbCr` to `RGB`.